# Render high resolution image as thumbnail fast

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Ruby on Rails 3.2

I have images around 1800 x 1200 pixels that I render to 220 x 180 pixels. The images are in the public directory. They take a little time to render, how would I make them render faster?

My view:

```
<% @images.each_slice(3) do |slice| %>
    <div class="row">
            <ul class="thumbnails">
                <% slice.each do |image| %>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <h4 style="text-align: center;"><%= File.basename(image) %></h4>
                    <% image_path = ["", File.dirname(image).split("public"),"/", File.basename(image)].join('') %>
                    <%= link_to image_tag(image_path), image_path[/\/.*/]%>
            </li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div> 
<% end %>
```

My style making the images thumbnails.

```
li.span3 img{
    width: 220px;
    max-height: 180px;
}
```

Any ideas to make them render faster? Maybe in the application controller loading the thumbnails for using app wide or something?

Comment: you need to make some thumbnails server-side - extremely inefficient to render such big images so small

Comment: So your suggestion is to make the thumbnails in the controller first? I'm nervous this will take too much time processing all the images rather than a few.

Comment: how about the controller makes a thumbnail if one doesn't already exist and then saves it - further calls for that thumbnail will then be quicker?

Comment: So save it as a global variable?

Comment: save it on the server

Comment: How do you take an array of images (png, jpg) and resize them into another array and save it on the server?

Comment: Maybe look at something like this http://www.dzone.com/snippets/easily-generate-thumbnails as your issue is that you are drawing big images, if the images are smaller they will render faster

Comment: From 2008, worried its not worth it. Does it even do anything different then what my CSS is doing?

Comment: Your CSS does not reduce the image size - it renders a massive image, that is what is taking so long, the download and render of a huge image. My point is that it would be faster to resize server-side and download that, the exact method to do that is what you should look into

Comment: I see, okay. So the answer to this question would be a Ruby on Rails way to take the array of images and resize each image into a thumbnail array.

Comment: Yes, resize is the answer, CSS does not resize the image, just renders it smaller

Comment: Well do you want to post an answer?

Comment: Don't render the thumbnails in a controller, or in anything that is based on an incoming URL or user action. Instead, run a separate task that looks for images without corresponding thumbnails, and then render them. Run that as a separate cron job every minute, or set up a notifier on your OS that triggers the job when an image lands on disk or changes. See https://github.com/nex3/rb-inotify

Comment: @theTinMan Interesting, this sounds like a better solution. A good Bj sounds like fun ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS does not reduce the image size - it renders a massive image, that is what is taking so long, the download and render of a huge image.

It would be faster to resize server-side and download that, the exact method to do that is what you should look into  - a quick google found:

http://www.dzone.com/snippets/easily-generate-thumbnails

Comment: +1 Good information, I will make an array of thumbnail size images in my controller or in a model from the original array of full size images.